# console.log doesn't work from chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need to execute script once user clicked my context menu item.

So for the purpose I created the context menu from my background js:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": title, "contexts": contexts,
                                       "onclick": genericOnClick});
```

It appears as expected. Later on from the genericOnClick I try to execute my script:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {code: "console.log('test 1');"}, function() {
      console.log("test 2");
  });
```

I can see that the "test 2" is printed to console but "test 1" never gets printed. What am I doing wrong?
I've tried adding the console.log sentence to a separate js file but it failed to print it as well:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {"file": 'content_script.js'}, function() {
      console.log("test 2");
  });
```

Note: my content_script.js is not defined in manifest. My manifest looks like follows:

```
{
  "name": "My First Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Sample extension",
  "page_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "tabs",
    "contextMenus"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["sample.js"]
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png"
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// addListener
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "content_script.js"}, function() {

        console.log("test 2");
    });
});


 // Context Menu
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    title: myTitle,
    contexts: ['page'],
    onclick: function (detail, tab) { fn(tab) }
});
```

so;

```
"permissions": [
"tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
]

chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{code:"document.body.style.backgroundColor='red'"});
```

or:

```
// Functional structure
function hi() { alert("hi"); };

// hi function toString after run  function (hi)()
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "(" + hi.toString() + ")()" });
```

Comment: Yes your code works fine, but if I change the document.body.style.backgroundColor='red' to some console.log sentence it still doesn't work. How should I debug the code then?

Comment: try function hi() sample ok ?

Answer (score 2):

The only piece of code from your extension that has access to the **console** is the *content script* that is injected into the original page.

From your code it looks like you are trying to write to the console from a *background script*. So, to write to the console from a background page you've to inject a *content script* to do the job for you.

In my extensions I use my own *function* to write messages to the console from a *background script*. The code for the same is given below:

```
function logMessage(msg){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code:"console.log('"+msg+"')"});
}
```

Define the above as the first function in your background script and call it from anywhere in the *background script* to write messages to the console.

In your case you can use this from the *genericOnClick* function to write messages to the console.