# How to use console.log when debugging tabs.executeScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have been looking for the answer to this question, but it only took me to the solution for debugging the extension itself, while I want to debug the webpage.

I want to create an extension that allows me to modify a particular web page (obviously only on my computer).
I have created a very simple script following the `"activeTab"` permission tutorial on the chrome developer's site, then I have made the following:

```
// Called when the user clicks on the browser action.
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code:'
      var oSwitchContainer = document.getElementById("norm");
      console.log(oSwitchContainer.childNodes);
    '
  });
});
```

When I inspect the page I cannot see any console messages, however, I can change the content of that `oSwitchContainer` easily by modifying its `innerHTML`.

Is there any way to see the console logs of the page after I enable the extension?

Comment: @jfriend00 Incorrect duplicate! The output of that command is NOT in the context of the background page.

Comment: @Xan - The output of what command?  I don't understand your comment.  We should also hear for the OP on that subject.  They've been strangely silent.

Comment: I fully understand the question and can provide an answer. `console.log` statement does not execute in the background, and that question does not apply. Please reopen.

Comment: @Xan - I thought the question was how to use `console.log()` in an extension and that's what that dup question shows you.  What do you think differently?  And, if the OP disagrees, they should comment.

Comment: No, this is not the question. This has to do with how `executeScript` operates. Do you understand it?

Comment: @Xan - So, are you saying it's a dup of this [console.log doesn't work from chrome.tabs.executeScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615515/console-log-doesnt-work-from-chrome-tabs-executescript)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71868/discussion-between-xan-and-jfriend00).

Comment: @Xan - I reopened.  I'm not convinced yet that there isn't a dup of this question and shame on the OP for being absent after posting and not commenting on whether the dup solved their issue or not.  Normally if an OP doesn't object or explain why the dup doesn't work for them, I'd leave it - after all, they're the one that should know.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you found solutions to debug "the extension itself".

Take a look at the [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

What you refer to as "extension itself" is its background page, and that's where your `browserAction.onClicked` listener executes. If you execute `console.log()` statements from that code, it will go to the background page's console.

However, using `chrome.tabs.executeScript`, you pass code to be executed in the context<sup>1</sup> of an open tab instead of executing it in the background page. All `console.log()` calls from that context go to the open page's own console - you should look there.

```
console.log("This will show in the background page console");
chrome.tabs.executeScript(
  { code: 'console.log("This will show in the current tab console");' }
);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> To be precise, the extension creates an isolated context, but it still belongs to the open page. See [Content Scripts documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, actually I have found the solution by checking how another extension worked and all I needed to do was having a different manifest.json file, which included certain commands, now everything is working smoothly and I am ready to more new struggles :D

Comment: Hm, looks like you went with injecting content scripts through manifest? Then you lose the advantages of `activeTab`, but gain automatic execution instead of clicking on the button. I assume those are the changes you mention.

Comment: Yes, I think I have learned more by editing an existing extension than by reading google documentation lol :)
Now I have separate files and folders and everything is tidier :)